# Proof that a continuous function with $f(x) = f(x^2)$ is constant.

Tags: analysis, continuity, functional-equations

Given a continuous function
$$
f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \quad \text{with} \quad f(x) = f(x^2) \quad\quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}
$$

How can I show that $f$ must be constant?

Comment: please add some of your thoughts and approaches and we will be happy to guide you further

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$f$ is an even function.
let $x> 0$ and $n\geq 0$.
we have
$$f(x^2)=f(x)=f(\sqrt{x})=$$
$$f(x^{\frac{1}{2^n}}).$$

by continuity of $f$,

when $ n\to +\infty, f(x)=f(1)$.

and  $f(0)=f(1)$.